# Rails4: How could ActiveRecord.find return an object with a different id to the one queried?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an issue where ActiveRecord.find is returning incorrect rows, but only in production. Here's some sample code:

```
    <% puts group_hash %>
    <% puts Group.find(group_hash['id'].to_i).inspect %>
```

which outputs: (all attributes other than 'id' have been truncated for readability)

```
    {"id"=>550058, ....}
    #<Group id: 265492, ...>
```

**How can Group.find(550058) be yielding a record with the id 265492?**

I believe a similar issue is happening in a few places. It seems to happen when the record has been loaded recently (in the above sample, the group is loaded previously in the controller), so I suspect the cache.

The code has been running fine under Rails3, the moment Rails4 is deployed, this issue happens.  Unfortunately I can't reproduce the issue in any non-production environments (even on a complete clone of production on a separate host, pointing at the production database), so possibly the server load is a contributing factor.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output of `Group.find(group_hash['id']).to_sql`? Note: your group_hash['id'] is already an int.

Comment: Did you try something like: `Group.where(id: group_hash['id'])` or `Group.find_by(id: group_hash['id'])`? And really, which sql produces your request?

Comment: I'll run some more tests & capture the SQL output. @AntonTsapov wouldn't your `Group.where` & `Group.find_by` examples yield the same sql as `Group.find`?

Comment: `Group.find(7)` will produce `SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]`. And `Group.find_by(id: 7)` or `Group.where(id: 7).first` will do `SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = 7 LIMIT 1`. Thats why I asked you about these two methods.

Comment: Have you found the problem? If not, maybe you need to check groups with ids `550058` and `265492` in rails console? Or in db directly.

Comment: @AntonTsapov thank you for your help, I appreciate it. I have only been using `find` when looking up single records. I didn't manage to find what caused the problem specifically, but I managed to resolve it by updating my heroku buildpack and gems. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this. I still have no idea how or why the above could have happened (surely `m = Model.find(id); (id == m.id)` should always be true!), though I still suspect the cache, as it seemed to only happen if the cache was primed.

I did the following, I believe something in these steps resolved the issue:

1. pruned my `Gemfile` removing some unused gems like dalli, and removing the version constraint all but a few cases to allow updating.
2. run `bundle update` resulting in a lot of updated dependancies
3. I'm was used a custom buildpack on Heroku (forked from the official ruby one), I pulled in the last few months of upstream changes.

Thanks to everyone who read & commented. I guess something was just amiss in my gem dependancies or heroku environment.